# Activity not started

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

In my OnClick event attached to an imageview, I want to open a new activity with a screensized imageview on it to show the picture.

This is the event:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    PhotoList pli = (PhotoList) arg0.getTag();
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PhotoActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("photo", pli.Photo);
    i.putExtra("PhotoId", pli.id);
    getBaseContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

This code is being executed when I click on the image, but nothing happens.

The onCreate of PhotoActivity (which is never executed):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    photo = extras.getByteArray("photo");
    ViewId = extras.getInt("View");
    PhotoId = extras.getInt("PhotoId");

    if (photo.length > 0) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pvPhoto);

        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
        iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
    }
```

The manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="enn.com.sitefinder.MainActivity" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PhotoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_photo" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="enn.com.sitefinder.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

When I accidently connected the OnClick eventlistener to the linear layout, the activity did start.

Why is the activity not shown?

Comment: Why are you using `getBaseContext()`. If you are in the activity itself, you do not need to call it, and use `ClassNameOfActivity.this` of `this`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by passing on a extra integer in the extras, allowing the PhotoActivity class to find the image in the arraylist.
This instead of passing the bitmap byte array which is too much for the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to use getBaseContext.startActivity

just use startActivity(intent);